# How can I come up with a formula for a vector field from a vector field picture?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Let's say I have a vector field like shown in the figure and I need to figure out a formula for it then how should I do it?

[image]

I did find one question that was posted here a while back relating to this question but the answer I needed wasn't answered.

Comment: Direction? How is the length varying? Of course, all you can do is to make an intelligent guess based on the diagram.

Comment: That looks like $(x^2,0)$ or $(|x|,0)$.

Comment: @mr_e_man You are correct, I checked both of them through a vector fields grapher, and they both look similar. (x^2, 0) is the correct one. Can please explain how you got to those answers so I can understand the process?

Comment: $x^2$ is wrong. Note the length of the arrow at $2$ is double the length at $1$. The vector field is independent of $y$ and the same at $(\pm x,y)$, so what’s left?

Comment: @TedShifrin could you please explain why that is wrong? Because when I put the formula into an online grapher it shows me the same graph as the one above. This [website](https://www.geogebra.org/m/QPE4PaDZ) is the one I am using. Vx = x^2, Vy = 0, xmin = -3, xmax = 3, ymin = -2, ymax = 2, xn = 5, yn = 5. And what do you mean by what's left?

Comment: Try putting $|x|$ instead. Compare the lengths of the arrows carefully.

Comment: @TedShifrin I did and |x| makes the arrow come to 2 instead of coming a bit after two. I am trying to get a formula that looks close to what the graph of the vector field is, unless I am not understanding it correctly

Comment: OK, so we need to rescale by a constant factor. Compare lengths in the original. What should the scale factor be, approximately?

Comment: @TedShifrin 2.5 and -2.5 for the y and x-axis for the graph. I am comparing it by 3 and -3 for the y and x-axis since it doesn't have an option for decimals.

Comment: I don't follow. It looks to me like the vector at $x=1$ has length approximately $1/5$, so I would say the vector field is $\vec F = (|x|/5)\vec i = (|x|/5,0)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, that makes sense. I thought you meant the scale of the graph lol. Sorry about that confusion.

Comment: @TedShifrin so |x| makes everything equal to positive which makes the arrows point right since that's where they are headed and doing (|x| / 5) makes the arrow's length 1/5 of whatever |x| is? Also if y = 0 then how come the arrows are in (-1, 1), (-1,1.5) etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141134/discussion-between-111-and-ted-shifrin).